# Why are PCB-mount AC DC converters so expensive?

Tags: pcb, ac-dc, cost

In a thrown-together prototype, I used a few wall warts to get the various voltages I needed. Now, I'm trying to build a cleaner version with a single plug and put it all on a PCB to eliminate my rats nest. The board mount versions are way more expensive though. I can get a [2A 12V wall wart for $6.22](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006NTNGN0) but a [2A 12V board mount converter is $27](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/VCP24US12-E/1470-2272-ND/4488651). Why the huge difference? Am I missing some more reasonably priced version of the board mount version?

Comment: Compare specs sizes and quality, and then find a wall wart that is the same for that price.

Comment: What's the difference between having a plug for the AC input to your board over a plug for the 12V wall wart? That wall wart even comes with a screw terminal header. The board mount converter probably uses better components and has better specs. Since it's mounted to a PCB host then it probably has better protection, EMI filtering and suppression as well.

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design. Question should be closed.

Comment: Keep in mind, if you're planning to sell a product, that if mains voltage enters your device, you may need to go through safety certification (e. g. UL) on your device. If you use a safety-certified wall-wart to provide low-voltage to your device, this will probably satisfy your customer's safety requirements.

Comment: Consider using an external off-the-shelf converter to one voltage (maybe 12V) and then DC-DC converters on your board to the other voltages you need.

Comment: Since the answers will probably be revolving around spec guesses and non-EE factors like economic of scale, I feel this should remain closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to compare apples to apples. The board mount converter you've listed has several key specifications (just to name a few):

- 2% load regulation
- 0.5% max line regulation
- 2% initial accuracy
- 0.2%/C tempco
- 0-70 degrees C operating conditions
- 100mV ripple/noise
- OVP, overload protection, and short circuit protection
- ~80% efficiency

That wall wart guarantees none of these (doesn't mean it has none of these, but you're not guaranteed any of these).

While not directly comparable, [this AC-DC brick](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/AD2412N3L/454-1435-ND/2203561) is more comparable in terms of accuracy, temperature range, and other features, and sells for 22.12 USD (there are still many differences in features). It's still cheaper than the board-mount brick, but much closer in price range. Perhaps there still is a difference in production scale as Spehro stated, and maybe some of the features in one are simply harder/more expensive to get than the other.

Answer (score 13):

The main difference is that the volume of production for board-mounted AC-DC converters is very low, so you pay a boutique price.

Decent quality fully approved (safety and EMC) wall-wart adapters are made in huge volume so the costs are relatively low.

When was the last time you saw an AC-DC converter module in a consumer product? Usually it's either a wall wart, or an open-frame power supply or a custom power supply board.

Comment: The device OP linked to comes in both open and closed frame packages, the specs on that supply are pretty good, probably better than a run of the mill wallwart. XP Power also tends to be a OEM for supplies used in all kinds of commercial products, ive seen them used in manufacturing equipment where the premium is not seen as an issue. However seconding your point that its easier to let someone else handle the mains and use a wallwart or case mounted supply from another vendor that deals with the UL certs to make your life easier.